# 開発者アカウントでアプリ内課金のアイテムを使用したい

Tags: android, java, アプリ内課金, google-play

Androidで、Play Billing Library 1.0を使用しています。
サンプルのTrivialDrive_v2を使用していてわかったのですが、
開発者アカウント（デベロッパーセンターのアカウント）では、「購入」ができません。
「消費」という概念がある以上、それは仕方がないと思うのですが、
自分で開発し、Playストアに公開したアプリを、Playストアからインストールした場合、
TrivialDrive_v2でいうところのPremiumの機能を購入できないため、フル機能を使うことができないと思います。
Play Billing Libraryで、開発者（オーナー）であることを識別し、TrivialDrive_v2でisPremiumPurchased()がtrueを返すように改変する方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: 普段使いのアカウント＝開発者アカウント のとき、普段使いのアカウントでアプリ内購入で開放する機能を使いたい。ということです。

Answer (score 2):

英語版stackoverflowに同様の質問を投げたところ、
１．アプリ内課金をもたずにフル機能を実装したアプリをアルファ版として公開し、自分だけで利用する。
２．Play Lecense Verification Libraryを利用し、userIDを取得し、そこにアプリ内課金と同様の機能を実装する。
との回答がありました。
Google Play Consoleチャットサポートに問い合わせたところ、新規アカウントを端末に登録し、そのアカウントでインストールすることでアプリ内購入が可能である。との回答を得ました。
どれも面倒または実装が難しいかですが、要は普段使いのアカウントがデベロッパーコンソールのアカウントと別であればよいことと、デベロッパーアカウントは別のアカウントにすべてのアプリを委譲し、継続公開できることがわかったため、新規アカウントでデベロッパー登録し、アプリを委譲することで解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

ヘルプを参照すると、「アプリ内課金をテストするにはアルファ版またはベータ版としてアプリを公開する必要がある」と書かれています。

[アプリ内課金のテスト | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

Comment: アルファ版、ベータ版、もっといえば製品版としてアプリを公開しても、開発者アカウントと同じアカウントでPlayストアからインストールすると、アプリ内購入はできません。しかし、普段使いのアカウントが開発者アカウントと同じ場合、アプリ内購入してフル機能を使いたいと思うのは当然で、その対処方法が知りたいです。